# Place Outlook Email in Excel without saving the Email

Tags: excel, outlook, embed

I have a friend that really wants to embed emails from outlook into an excel file to store some conversations. They use multiple computers without a roaming desktop so saving the file to the desktop is not an option. Every other place they have to save data is visible by all employees and they want to keep others from seeing this. We were curious if there is a way to embed the email directly into the excel itself instead of as a link to a file.